# ActionScript multiple object instantiation hitTestPoint

Tags: flash, actionscript, flash-cs5

The problem I am having is basically, I am instantiating the 'Target' object five times on the stage. This is happening, but only one object is able to have hitTestPoint performed on it. Can anyone help as to why this is happening?

Here is the code:

**UPDATED**

```
package {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.text.*;

public class TheGameItself extends Sprite {

    public var main_class:TheGame;
    private var crosshair:Crosshair = new Crosshair;
    private var targets:Array = new Array();

    public function TheGameItself(passed_class:TheGame) {

        main_class = passed_class;

        addTargets(4);

        Mouse.hide();
        addChild(crosshair);
        crosshair.x = mouseX;
        crosshair.y = mouseY;
        addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVE, moveCrosshair);
    }

    private function addTargets(numOfTargets:int):void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfTargets; ++i) {
            targets[i] = new Target;
            targets[i].x = 100 * i + 70;
            targets[i].y = 100;
            targets[i].scaleX = targets[i].scaleY = .7;
            addChild(targets[i]);
            addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, collisionDetection);
        }
    }

    private function collisionDetection(e:MouseEvent):void {
        targets.forEach(detectCollision);
    }

    private function detectCollision(element:*, index:int, targets:Array):void {
        if (element.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true) && targets.length > 0) {
            trace("["+index+"]"+" "+element);
            collisionNotification.text = "Yes";
        } else {
            collisionNotification.text = "No";
        }
    }

    public function moveCrosshair(e:MouseEvent):void {
        crosshair.x = mouseX;
        crosshair.y = mouseY;
    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your targets to an array to keep track of then:

```
private function target:Array = new Array();

private function newTarget(numOfTargets:uint):void {
        for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfTargets; i++) {
            target[i] = new Target;
            target[i].x = 100 * i + 70;
            target[i].y = 100;
            target[i].scaleX = target[i].scaleY = .7;
            addChild(target[i]);
            trace(target[i]); // Adds 5 objects to stage

            //**updated**
            target[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, collisionDetection); 
        }
}
```

now you can refer to each individual target:

```
private function collisionDetection(e:MouseEvent):void {

var target:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target); //**updated**

        if (target.hitTestPoint(mouseX, mouseY, true)) {
            collisionNotification.text = "Collision";
            removeTarget();
            currentScore.text = String(int(score));
        } else {
            collisionNotification.text = "No collision";
            decreaseScore();
            currentScore.text = String(int(score));
            // Check if score is equal to -200 and if it is, show game over screen
            if (score == -500) {
                Mouse.show();
                main_class.showGameOver();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help - but it doesn't seem to work. I understand what's going on in your example, but the problem remains effectively the same. Only 1 object is 'clickable' by the mouse, the rest are unresponsive.

Comment: My guess is that you are only adding one event to handle all targets, the correct way is in adding one event to each target in the loop. I edit my previous code, have a look where I marked with //**updated**

Comment: Those were my initial thoughts with this problem, that I was only listening for the hitTestPoint event on only the first object and not all of them. I've tried your updated solution, but to no avail.

I have implemented your original solution, and added to it in an attempt to solve my problem. I have updated the code in my original question. Take a look at it and see what you think.

Comment: ...What interesting is that when I click on ANY one of the instantiated objects on the stage, the line `trace("["+index+"]"+" "+element);` fires for each one and displays `[X] [object Target]`, but it doesn't update the collisionNotification.text textfield!

Comment: Im not sure what could be causing the problem. Try changing this line inside the loop "addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, collisionDetection);" to "target[i].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, collisionDetection);"

Comment: I have managed to get it working, thanks for your assistance.